# When run a tensorflow session in iPython, GPU memory usage remain high when exiting iPython

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython

I think it's some sort of bug.

The problem is quite simple:

1. launch ipython
2. import Tensorflow and run whatever session
3. type nvidia-smi in bash (see really high gpu memory usage, related process name, etc)
4. control+z quit ipython
5. type nvidia-smi in bash (still! really high GPU memory usage, and the same process name, strangely, these processes are not killed!)

I guess iPython failed to clean Tensorflow variables or graphs when exiting.

Is there any way I can clean the GPU memory without restart my machine?

System: Ubuntu 14.04
Python: Python3.5
IPython: IPython6.0.0

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control+Z doesn't quit a process, it stops it (use `fg` to bring it back up). If some computation is running in a forked process, it may not stop with the main process (I'm no OS guy, this is just my intuition).

In any case, properly quitting iPython (e.g. by Control+D or by running `exit()`) should solve the problem. If you need to interrupt a running command, first hit Control+C, then run `exit()`.